# Add Double-Quote on Header of Blob file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Copy data activity, where the source is SQL Server Query and sink is a blob file.

The blob file is created successfully but it doesn't have a double-quote in the header, same as the rows. Can that be configured in ADF?

Blob file:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution without creating another Copy Activity. In the Mapping section of the copy activity, just add double-quote (") on the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible in Azure Datafactory. As we explicitly declare the `First row as header` then it's going to take the first row as column names and wont be having double quotes same as rows. Because, `Quote character` & `Escape characters` is only for the rows, you can avoid having quotes in the rows as well.

[image]

Here, is the way you can have double quotes only when you again run a Copy Activity using the previous `output blob file` as source and sink as to another blob then it could be possible, and eliminating to declare `Row as header` for both source and sink datasets:

[image]

Comment: @kayeesp - If you find my answer useful and it helped you to resolve your issue, could you please accept it as an answer( click on tick mark on left side of answer) to help other community members,